# Python code using multiprocessing running infinitely

Tags: python, multiprocessing, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I am trying to execute the following code in jupyter notebook using multiprocessing but the loop is running infinitely.
I need help resolving this issue.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np

def square(x):
    return np.square(x)

x = np.arange(64)

pool = mp.Pool(4)
squared = pool.map(square, [x[16*i:16*i+16] for i in range(4)])
```

The output for  `mp.cpu_count()` was 4.

Comment: Which operating system? If `multiprocessing.get_start_method()` returns "spawn", your code needs to be protected with a `if __name__ == "__main__"` (see Safe importing of main module at https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite your code to be something like:

```
def main():
    x = np.arange(64)
    pool = mp.Pool(4)
    squared = .....

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code is currently being run in every process.  You need it to only run in the one process that is doing the setup.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot:

```
pool.close()
pool.join()
```